# How can I ensure that one spring-boot-starter is loaded before another?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying to ensure that one Spring Boot Starter is loaded before another. In this case, I have a custom spring boot starter written by my organization and the spring-boot-starter-data-jpa starter. It's crucial that the custom starter's bean is ran before spring-boot-starter-data-jpa is initialized. An example snippet of the dependencies in pom.xml:

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-my-customer-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

How would one go about this? The solution I'm currently considering is adding a `@Primary` annotation to the top of the bean initialized in my company's custom starter, not sure if this would work and looking for best practice here. The bean I'm attempting to load in the custom starter before spring-boot-starter-jpa's beans are loaded is responsible for setting proxy settings, therefore must be loaded first so that traffic to the database can be routed via proxy.

Comment: I think you are confusing things here. The dependency/build system has nothing to do with the way the CDI container (Spring in this case) loads the various beans. On top of that your question does not really state the reason and what this beans does in order to provide a clearer explanation of the issue. Please try to add more information.

Comment: @akortex Thanks for the feedback, I've added some context around what the bean does.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure as to what you are trying to achieve here, but a way of controlling bean creation could be done using the [DependsOn](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/DependsOn.html) annotation.

In you case, since you would like to initialize your custom bean before the actual database connection is made, I think that adding this to your database configuration class should be enough.